# Filter properties of class instance by specific attribute and invoke method of property

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with some properties in it. Some specific properties are decorated with an attribute.  For example:

```
public class CoreAddress
{
    private ContactStringProperty _LastName;

    [ChangeRequestField]
    public ContactStringProperty LastName
    {
        //ContactStringProperty has a method SameValueAs(ContactStringProperty other)
        get { return this._LastName; }
    }
    .....
}
```

I want to have a method in my class which walks through all my properties of this class, filters the one with this custom attribute and invokes a member of the found properties.  This is what I have so far:

```
foreach (var p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //checking if it's a change request field
            if (p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChangeRequestFieldAttribute), false).Count() > 0)
            {

                MethodInfo method = p.PropertyType.GetMethod("SameValueAs");
                //problem here        
                var res = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { other.LastName }); 

            }

        }
```

If this method is an instance method of the property I have to provide a target (instead of null as in the code). How do I get the specific property of this class instance at runtime?

Comment: If you know everything about the class why do you use reflection? Or you want to process some properties of descendants?

Comment: It's actually used to avoid lots of error prone manual property checking, plus when a developer adds a property with this attribute it is automatically being included in the method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the PropertyInfo, you can call the [`GetValue method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx). So...

```
MethodInfo method = p.PropertyType.GetMethod("SameValueAs");
//problem solved
var propValue = p.GetValue(this);

var res = method.Invoke(propValue, new object[] { other.LastName });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) to get the value of any property you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value out of the property and use it like you would normally.

```
foreach (var p in type.GetProperties())
{
         if (p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChangeRequestFieldAttribute), false).Count() > 0)
         {

               //just get the value of the property & cast it.
               var propertyValue = p.GetValue(<the instance>, null);
               if (propertyValue !=null && propertyValue is ContactStringProperty)
               {
                   var contactString = (ContactStringProperty)property;
                   contactString.SameValueAs(...);
               }
         }
  }
```